# Redirecting URLs to a new subdomain with Open Cart

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, opencart

I have recently moved a client's e-commerce Open Cart site from theirdomain.com to shop.theirdomain.com and replaced theirdomain.com with a standard local business wordpress site.

The move went smoothly, however there are a number of pages from the original theirdomain.com that are still indexed in Google and are displaying 404 errors obviously.

I want to add 301 redirects to these pages in the htacess file to their respective subdomain pages, but when I tried the following code, the redirect worked, but the page wouldn't load properly.

Redirect 301 /carb-caps http://shop.theirdomain.com/carb-caps

It would take me to a page like this [http://shop.theirdomain.com/carb-caps?*route*=carb-caps&*route*=carb-caps&*route*=carb-caps&*route*=carb-caps&*route*=carb-caps&*route*=carb-caps&*route*=carb-caps&*route*=carb-caps&*route*=carb-caps&*route*=carb-caps&*route*=carb-caps&*route*=carb-caps&*route*=carb-caps&*route*=carb-caps&*route*=carb-caps&*route*=carb-caps&*route*=carb-caps&*route*=carb-caps&*route*=carb-caps&*route*=carb-caps](http://shop.theirdomain.com/carb-caps?_route_=carb-caps&_route_=carb-caps&_route_=carb-caps&_route_=carb-caps&_route_=carb-caps&_route_=carb-caps&_route_=carb-caps&_route_=carb-caps&_route_=carb-caps&_route_=carb-caps&_route_=carb-caps&_route_=carb-caps&_route_=carb-caps&_route_=carb-caps&_route_=carb-caps&_route_=carb-caps&_route_=carb-caps&_route_=carb-caps&_route_=carb-caps&_route_=carb-caps)

I understand that this is typical of Open Cart...

The page loads fine without the redirect in place, but as soon as I add the redirect to the htaccess file, it just doesn't load.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!